# How to refresh(reload) SAPUI5 oModel (oData)

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I have a following problem. I am able to properly call function UserDelete to delete a row with user data in table on SAP side but deleted object is still in oModel. How to refresh or destroy and recreate oModel ? I tried to use :

```
oModel.destroy();
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://plaut0001.plaut.pl:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZUSERINFO_SRV/",true,"developer","gliwice");   
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
```

but after this i got following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataServices' of undefined

below is the code I use to call function deleting user on SAP side:

```
//handle delete button
handleDelete : function(evt) {
    var context = evt.getSource().getBindingContext();
    var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
    oModel.callFunction('UserDelete', 'POST', 
            {Userid : context.getProperty("Userid")}, 
            null, 
            function(){sap.m.MessageBox.show("Pomyślnie usunięto");}, 
            function(){sap.m.MessageBox.show("Błąd");}
        );


    sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("nav", "to", {
        viewId : "app.details.Empty",
        data : "" 
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried oModel.refresh(true,true); ?

Comment: Yes. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the service after the remove command in your code. Please provide sample Jsbin link that you have already tried.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a newbie in javascript. Can give some hints how to do this?